# An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I just ran my program and I got this error message

> An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current
>   web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about
>   the error and where it originated in the code.

with stack trace

```
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   OverseasCreditCard.Default.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) +667
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +70
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3177
```

I am using ASP.NET C#, does anyone know what happened?

Comment: you have an error in your `Page_Load`

Comment: One of the variables/objects you are trying to access in `Page_load` is `null`. Put a break point in the method and debug it to find it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Incomplete information: we need to know which line is throwing the **NullReferenceException** in order to tell precisely where the problem lies.

Obviously, you are using an uninitialized variable (i.e., a variable that has been declared but not initialized) and try to access one of its non-static method/property/whatever.

**Solution**:
- Find the line that is throwing the exception from the exception details
- In this line, check that every variable you are using has been correctly initialized (i.e., it is not null)

Good luck.

Comment: This is not an answer. This is a request for information with at best some guidelines to troubleshoot the error.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and found out that I had forgotten to include the script in the file which I want to include in the live site.

Also, you should try this:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
"~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code with line 156, it has try and catch above it

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Execute a SQL Query statement, using the default SQL connection for the application
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="query">SQL query to execute</param>
    /// <returns>DataTable of results</returns>
    public static DataTable Query(string query)
    {
        DataTable results = new DataTable();
        string configConnectionString = "ApplicationServices";

        System.Configuration.Configuration WebConfig = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~/Web.config");
        System.Configuration.ConnectionStringSettings connString;

        if (WebConfig.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings.Count > 0)
        {
            connString = WebConfig.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings[configConnectionString];

            if (connString != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString.ToString()))
                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
                    using (SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                        dataAdapter.Fill(results);

                    return results;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw new SqlException(string.Format("SqlException occurred during query execution: ", ex));
                }
            }
            else
            {
                throw new SqlException(string.Format("Connection string for " + configConnectionString + "is null."));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            throw new SqlException(string.Format("No connection strings found in Web.config file."));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. If you are facing this problem (Enter windows + R) an delete temp(%temp%)and windows temp.
2. Some file is not deleted that time stop IIS(Internet information service) and delete that all remaining files .

Check your problem is solved.